# Apple SSO Callback returns OAuth2::AccessToken.from_hash `hash` contained more than one 'token' key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, apple-id

I am trying to implement Apple SSO using the `omniauth_apple` gem in Ruby on Rails.

In my devise.rb, i have the following config

```
config.omniauth :apple, Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :apple_sso, :client_id), '', {
    scope: 'email name',
    team_id: Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :apple_sso, :team_id),
    key_id: Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :apple_sso, :key_id),
    pem: Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :apple_sso, :pem),
    redirect_uri: Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :apple_sso, :redirect_uri),
    provider_ignores_state: true
  }
```

In my omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb, i have the following

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:apple]
  protect_from_forgery prepend: true, only: :apple
  
  def apple
    puts "==== GOT INTO APPLE======="
    auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  end
end
```

My user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tenant(:tenant)

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :lockable,
    :timeoutable, :rememberable, :trackable, :confirmable, :zxcvbnable,
    :omniauthable, :jwt_authenticatable,
    jwt_revocation_strategy: JwtDenyList, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2, :facebook, :apple]
end
```

in my routes, i also have specification to receive callbacks for each provider

```
devise_for :users,
    only: :omniauth_callbacks,
    controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"}
```

Now when i click the Sign in with Apple button, it does redirect me to sign in my username and password from Apple but when the callback phase is initiated, it returns an error and does not redirect to the controller. I get this error but I honestly do not know how or where to start to resolve it

```
OAuth2::AccessToken.from_hash: `hash` contained more than one 'token' key (["access_token", "id_token"]); using "access_token".
(apple) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, id_token_claims_invalid | nonce invalid
```

Does anyone have experience using the omniauth_apple gem with Devise to setup and fully integrate Apple SSO on Rails? Please help

Comment: I faced a similar issue when users attempted to sign up with an SSO provider whose email, already associated with an existing account, exists in the user table. For example, let's say 'user-1' signed up with Google SSO or an email like 'user-1@gmail.com’ and attempts to log in with an Apple account whose email address is ‘user-1@gmail.com’. multiple access tokens will be created leading to this error.